# How to get particles simulation data directly from the cache via bpy?

Tags: python, particles, cache

Is there any way to get particles data directly from the cache via `bpy`? For example, I've added Emitter, baked some particle simulation and would like to get locations and rotations of the particles directly from the Cache instead of iterating through Scene frames and obtaining data from the depsgraph. Is it possible?